# What is the .scss variable for Bootstrap nav-tabs link hover color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have some simple markup for a tab link:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Active</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Archive</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to change color of the links on mouse hover.  Here are the Bootstrap 3.3.1 .scss variables

```
//=== Shared nav styles
// $nav-link-padding:                          10px 15px
// $nav-link-hover-bg:                         $gray-lighter
// $nav-disabled-link-color:                   $gray-light
// $nav-disabled-link-hover-color:             $gray-light
//== Tabs
// $nav-tabs-border-color:                     #ddd
// $nav-tabs-link-hover-border-color:          $gray-lighter
// $nav-tabs-active-link-hover-bg:             $body-bg
// $nav-tabs-active-link-hover-color:          $gray
// $nav-tabs-active-link-hover-border-color:   #ddd
// $nav-tabs-justified-link-border-color:            #ddd
// $nav-tabs-justified-active-link-border-color:     $body-bg
```

It seems that this every is variation except the one I wanted, which is `$nav-tabs-link-hover-color`.  Also, `$nav-tabs-active-link-hover-color` seems to change `active-link-color`, rather than `active-link-hover-color`. Where is `$nav-tabs-link-hover-color` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check variables.scss and find

```
$link-hover-color:      darken($link-color, 15%) !default;
```

I think for .nav-tabs a:hover, bootstrap is using default hover color used for anchors.